# Can not find where 177 GB is used

Tags: partitioning

This is my disk usage:

```
    ➜  / df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                       3.2G  164M  3.0G   6% /run
/dev/mapper/caner--vg-root  202G  177G   15G  93% /
tmpfs                        16G  444M   16G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1              511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                       3.2G  184K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda1       

        458G   14G  421G   4% /media/caner/Backup Data
```

There are two disks. Ubuntu is on 200 GB and there is 450 gbwith name of Backup Date

to see where 177 GB, i ran lots of commands but maximum I could find aroud 30 40 GB. There was docker file, i deleted it but still same.

for example

➜

```
  / sudo du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
du: cannot read directory 'proc/16350/task/16350/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory 'proc/16350/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access 'proc/23352/task/23352/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/23352/task/23352/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/23352/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/23352/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot read directory 'proc/24005/task/24005/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory 'proc/24005/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory 'proc/24638/task/24638/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory 'proc/24638/net': Invalid argument
21G     home
16G     var
5.7G    usr
918M    lib
716M    core
228M    opt
213M    boot
164M    run
138M    tmp
19M     sbin
```

and

```
➜  / cd home 
➜  /home sudo du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
21G     caner
```

and

```
➜  /home sudo du -shc *|grep "G"|sort -n
21G     caner
21G     total
```

and

```
➜  /home find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n | tail -10 | cut -f2 | xargs -I{} du -sh {}
du: cannot read directory './caner/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './caner/.dbus': Permission denied
find: ‘./caner/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘./caner/.dbus’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './caner/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './caner/.dbus': Permission denied
1.5G    ./caner/Program Files
3.1G    ./caner/.local/share/Steam/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo/maps
14G     ./caner/.local/share/Steam/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo
15G     ./caner/.local/share/Steam/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive
15G     ./caner/.local/share/Steam/common
16G     ./caner/.local/share/Steam
16G     ./caner/.local/share
16G     ./caner/.local
du: cannot read directory './caner/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './caner/.dbus': Permission denied
21G     ./caner
du: cannot read directory './caner/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory './caner/.dbus': Permission denied
21G     .
```

and

```
➜  /home sudo du -hxd1 /
19M     /sbin
4.0K    /snap
7.0G    /usr
360K    /root
16K     /lost+found
138M    /tmp
16M     /bin
213M    /boot
4.0K    /srv
228M    /opt
16G     /var
918M    /lib
12K     /media
4.0K    /mnt
5.6M    /libx32
21G     /home
5.7M    /lib64
5.2M    /lib32
16M     /etc
45G     /
```

and for `sudo lsof | grep deleted`

there are lots of

```
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  234w      REG              253,0            0    4720841 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.1562863332 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  235w      REG              253,0            0    4729349 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-unreads.834543481 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  236w      REG              253,0            0    4720843 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3663663653 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  237w      REG              253,0            0    4722397 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.87638799 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  238w      REG              253,0            0    4726821 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3441422984 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  239w      REG              253,0            0    4729009 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.2794492733 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  240w      REG              253,0            0    4726858 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3389138180 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  241w      REG              253,0            0    4726866 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3517754995 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  242w      REG              253,0            0    4726867 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.1803322046 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  243w      REG              253,0            0    4726942 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.1819890120 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  244w      REG              253,0            0    4727077 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3311408514 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  245w      REG              253,0            0    4727254 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.415290328 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  246w      REG              253,0            0    4727652 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.370231773 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  247w      REG              253,0            0    4723630 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3681320022 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  248w      REG              253,0            0    4725685 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.3881846422 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  249w      REG              253,0            0    4729429 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-windowFrame.2898607722 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  250w      REG              253,0            0    4730859 /home/caner/.config/Slack/storage/slack-appTeams.1947144843 (deleted)
BrowserBl 13392 20705               caner  251w      REG
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo du -hxd1 /`, please. And that of `sudo lsof | grep deleted`.

Comment: @muru added bottom of question

Comment: Maybe close Slack or restart your system.

Comment: Where is "*450 gbwith name of Backup Date*" mounted? often the cause of missing space is that files have been written to a mountpoint directory when the drive was not mounted - and then subsequently covered up (hence hidden from `du`) when it is mounted

Comment: steeldriver's suggestion is a good one. Another is that dot files might not appear in your `du` searches. If your system has, say, a `/.Trash` file, it could be filled with lots of files. Also, what filesystem are you using? Btrfs can create snapshots that can consume a lot of space but not show up in searches. If you're using ext4fs or most other filesystems, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @muru, I think you get the point, until the application block the files has been deleted the space are not released. A restart is an option or kill the process is block the files.